# Laravel server on infinite mail loop after a 404

Tags: laravel, email

My server is sending infinite mail with Laravel..
I tried testing a simple mail form, it returned a 404 and still sent a lot of e-mails. Now my server went crazy and is sending 14 e-mails per second on amazon SES.

I've tried:

- restarting server
- clearing the queue (no jobs are show in the database)
- checking if retry has a limit, it is set to 3
- went back to php5 (it was updated to 7 recently)

I'm using laravel 5.2.

My email sending logic:

```
\Mail::send('emails.contact', ['email_message' => $email_message, 'name' => $name], function($message) use ($to_email, $from_email, $name, $subject) {
            $message->to($to_email)->from('my@server.com', $name)->replyTo($from_email, $name)->subject($subject);
        });
```

PHP Log and Nginx logs shows no errors

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: Hard to say without information. Can you provide the logic around the sending of the email? also where you create that job, and check PHP logs and Laravel logs. Also you could add additional logs to some of the related code.

Comment: updated with some more info @NestorMataCuthbert

Comment: You need to expand your excerpt, clearly that is not all of your logic.

Comment: I would think the problem is in your code, you pretty much ruled out everything else. But, we would need more code to analyse, just the line that calls Mail::send that as much we guessed already. Have you checked the queues worker log/output ?